# Copying struct pointer element to a pointer seems to corrupt it

Tags: c

I'm still learning C and I must have misunderstood pointers at some point.

I was under the impression that the following lines would copy the memory address stored by `l->first` to `temp`. They are both `struct list_el*` pointers, so I can't see the problem.

```
struct list_elt * temp;
temp = l->first;
```

Running my sample code gives me an infinite loop:

```
user@machine:~$ gcc question.c 
user@machine:~$ ./a.out | head
append(): l->first->val: 30, l->first->next == NULL: 1
main()  : l->first->val: 30, l->first->next == NULL: 1
print() : l->first->val: 30, l->first->next == NULL: 1
print() : temp->val: 30, temp->next == NULL: 0
print() : temp->val: 30, temp->next == NULL: 0
print() : temp->val: 30, temp->next == NULL: 0
print() : temp->val: 30, temp->next == NULL: 0
print() : temp->val: 30, temp->next == NULL: 0
print() : temp->val: 30, temp->next == NULL: 0
print() : temp->val: 30, temp->next == NULL: 0
```

Here's `question.c`. I'm sorry I couldn't narrow it down further, every time I do the problem seems to magically go away.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list_elt {
    int val;
    struct list_elt * next;
};
struct linked_list {
    struct list_elt* first;
};

void print(const struct linked_list * l);
struct linked_list* new_list(void);
void append(struct linked_list* l, int value);


main()
{
    struct linked_list * l;
    l = new_list();
    append(l, 30);
    printf("main()  : l->first->val: %d, l->first->next == NULL: %d\n", l->first->val, l->first->next == NULL);
    print(l);
}

struct linked_list* new_list()
{
    struct linked_list* l;
    l = (struct linked_list*) malloc(sizeof(struct linked_list));
    l->first = NULL;
    return l;
}

void append(struct linked_list* l, int value)
{
    struct list_elt el = {0, NULL};
    el.val = value;
    el.next = NULL;
    if (l->first == NULL) {
        l->first = (struct list_elt*) &el;
        printf("append(): l->first->val: %d, l->first->next == NULL: %d\n", l->first->val, l->first->next == NULL);
    } else {
        printf("append(): Unimplemented\n");
    }
}


void print(const struct linked_list * l)
{
    printf("print() : l->first->val: %d, l->first->next == NULL: %d\n", l->first->val, l->first->next == NULL);
    struct list_elt * temp;
    temp = l->first;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("print() : temp->val: %d, temp->next == NULL: %d\n", temp->val, temp->next == NULL);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: seems like `homework` : if it's the case, tag it correctly, otherwise, use a library ;-)

Comment: Ugh! Don't name your objects `l`. If you must use a single letter, use any other letter (expect `I`, or `O`); but it's better to use more than 1 letter anyway.

Comment: The problem did come up in the context of homework, go ahead and add the correct tag if you want. I actually finished the piece of homework by replacing `el` with a pointer and using `malloc`, but I wanted to know why this version doesn't work.

Comment: Single letter variable names are horrible, I agree, but believe it or not this actually common practise of more than one of my lecturers. I should have renamed it for stackoverflow's benefit, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `append` function is wrong.  It is allocating `el` on the stack, and using the pointer in your list.  The problem with this is that the memory is will be overwritten with garbage as soon as another function is called after `append`, in this case, `print`.  Instead, allocate with malloc, something like:

```
int append(struct linked_list* l, int value)
{
    struct list_elt *el = malloc(sizeof(struct list_elt));

    if (el)
    {
        el->val = value;
        el->next = NULL;
        if (l->first == NULL) {
            l->first = el;
            printf("append(): l->first->val: %d, l->first->next == NULL: %d\n",
                   l->first->val, l->first->next == NULL);
        } else {
            printf("append(): Unimplemented\n");
        }

        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that in C, it is considered good practice *not* to cast the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: and it's considered good practice to check if malloc returned 0 / NULL before trying to use pointer.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Is it possible to still keep `el` as it was, a `list_elt` struct, rather than a pointer to one?

Comment: @Flimm, `el` has to be a pointer, as the memory for the struct needs to be allocated by `malloc`.  If you make it a value as you had done, the memory is allocated locally on the stack, and will be subject to being overwritten by another function call.

Answer (score 5):

You are allocating your list_elt on the stack of the `append` function. this pointer is invalid once the function returns, and should no longer be referenced.

You should allocate your elements with `malloc` instead.

Comment: @Flimm: Just assign directly to `l->first`.  i.e. `l->first = malloc(sizeof(*l->first));`.

Comment: @Flimm: As Oli Charlesworth says. also, you should check if `malloc` returned `NULL` before trying to dereference the pointer and set its fields. (you should also be doing this in your `new_list` function)

Answer (score 3):

In `append()`, you are setting `l->first` to the address of a *local* stack variable, `el`.  But `el` goes out of scope as soon as `append()` returns, so any attempt to dereference `l->first` afterwards is *undefined behaviour*.

Answer (score 3):

*(What follows is a very simple explanation, so simple that it's arguably unprecise. I went for simplicity, but you can learn more by googling about the stack and the heap in C).*

There are basically two ways to create things and store them in memory: **use the stack, or request memory to the Operating System**.

**The *stack* is temporary memory**, used to keep track of the **current execution context**. Every time you call a function, a sector of the stack is used to store all the local variables. This is what you're doing in `append()`: **using temporary memory located in the stack to store your new list node**.

Anything in the *stack* (any local variables) **is considered lost in time and space when you return from the function**, since the current execution context is no longer relevant, and this memory is reused for another context (the next function call, for example). This is unavoidable, it's a consequence of how this memory is managed, and it occurs outside your direct reach in C (or rather, you shouldn't mess with it).

When you want to store something outside this local scope, relevant to your program in general and not just to the current execution context, **you must request additional memory to the operating system** -- this temporary *stack* won't do. There are numerous functions for this -- check out the simplest, called `malloc()`.

Hope it helped. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. That did help. All the guides on pointers that I've read don't explain the stack, so this was helpful.

Is the stack the same as static memory allocation, or is the latter something different?

Comment: No, it's not the same. As I said, the stack is temporary and stores the execution context, it changes constantly in runtime. `static memory` is called `static` because it's reserved for you before execution really starts, and does not change during runtime. Declaring static variables, for example, will give you static memory space.

Comment: +1: This is pretty accurate, actually.  My only quibble is with the mention of "operating system".  There isn't necessarily an OS involved in dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 0):

In append, your element is created on stack and referenced later : this is wrong. When your function exits your `el` variable does not exist any more. You need to malloc your list_elt.